# Using Buttons and FragmentManager in Android

Tags: android

I am learning Fragments in Android from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6iHGTS4-wWs&t=621s)(04:05:42) tutorial.

[image]

1)Why are we not using `setOnClickListener` method while using button?

2)`FragmentManager` looks like a class and `fm` its object. `getFragmentManager()` seems like a method.

In Java, we are familiar with the syntax:

```
ClassA a = new ClassA();
```

Where,

`ClassA` is the class.

`a` is the object of `ClassA`.

and

`ClassA()` is the constructor.

Then, why is the syntax like:

```
   ClassA b=method_c();
```

?

Comment: do you know about return types of a method ?

Comment: You ask **us** why **they** do that. Why do you do this? How can we know why he did this or that?

Comment: `why is the syntax like:` you are missing Java basics. Please pass through some Java tutorial before you continue

Comment: @VivekMishra Return type of a method can be built-in and user defined objects. https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/methods . So, the method getFragmentManager() returns an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `getFragmentManager()` returns a `FragmentManager` instance

```
@Deprecated
public FragmentManager getFragmentManager() {
    return mFragments.getFragmentManager();
}
```

`ClassA a = new ClassA();` is not the only way you can initialize a class there are many other ways , consider this example initializing with return type

```
ClassA a = getClassA();

private ClassA getClassA(){
    return new ClassA();  //not exactly same as FragmentManager
 }
```

also `getFragmentManager()` is deprecated use `getSupportFragmentManager()`
and 
use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` instead of `android.app.Fragment`